# StopWatch in separate thread restart

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, packet, stopwatch

I have a client - server application and I want to check periodically if client has disconnected from server.

I have decided that I will check for incoming packets. If i received any in time span of let say 15 seconds I have a valid connection,
if not I have disconnected and will try to reconnect.

So far I have this sample code (this is sample recreated from my code):

```
namespace TimerExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           HandlePackets();
        }

        public void HandlePackets()
        {
            //code that handles incomming packets
            foo test = new foo();

            test.StartThread();
        }
    }

    class foo
    {
        public bool _isRunning { get; set; }
        private Stopwatch sw { get; set; }

        public void StartThread()
        {
            this._isRunning = true;
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.DoWork)).Start();

            this.sw.Restart();
        }

        public void StopThread()
        {
            this._isRunning = false;
            this.sw.Stop();
        }

        private void DoWork()
        {
            while (this._isRunning)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Elapsed in miliseconds: " + this.GetRuntime().ToString());

                if (GetRuntime() > 15000)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected.... restarting");
                    this.StopThread();
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        public long GetRuntime()
        {
            return this.sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        public foo()
        {
            _isRunning = false;
            sw = new Stopwatch();
        }
    }
}
```

What I want for code to be doing is: Function `HandlePackets` will be executed every time packet will arrive. Inside that function I will call
function `StartThread` which will run `Stopwatch` in separate thread and this process will go on as long as `stopwatch` elapsed time in milliseconds 
won't be bigger than lets say 15 seconds.

If it will I will call `Reconnect`.

So basically timer will restart every time a packet is received and reconnect will be called if `ElapsedTime` will be greater than 15 seconds.

Comment: I don't actually see a question here.  What are you asking?  What's wrong with the code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to implement this mechanism.

Creating thread is the worst one.
Be careful - accessing Stopwatch instance members from multiple threads is not safe.

One easy and straightforward solution is to create `ThreadPool Timer` that ticks let's say every 15 seconds and checks boolean variable via `Volatile.Read`. Once boolean variable is False - you can re-connect. 
From receiver thread you just need to set variable using `Volatile.Write` true. This does not consume resources when receiving (almost).

In many of the implementations could be races because of re-connection mechanism that can start a moment before new packet arrives. The easiest and rogue way to improve this is to stop timer right before you decide to re-connect and start it again once connection is done. You must understand that there is no way to solve this false-reconnection issue.

The method above works pretty much like WatchDog

From design perspective I would recommend you create classes : Receiver and WatchDog and ConnectionManager

```
// Receives and processes data
class Receiver : IDisposable
{
  public Receiver(WatchDog watchDog);
  public void LoopReceive(); // Tick watch dog on every packet
  public void Dispose();
}

// Setups timer and periodically checks if receiver is alive.
// If its not, it asks manager to reconnect and disposes receiver
class WatchDog : IDisposable
{
  public WatchDog(ConnectionFactory factory);
  // Setups timer, performs Volatile.Read and if receiver is dead, call dispose on it and ask manager to reconnect.
  public void StartWatching(IDisposable subject);
  public void Tick(); // Volatile.Write
  public void Dispose();
}

// Can re-connect and create new instances of timer and watchdog
// Holds instance variable of receiver created
class ConnectionManager
{
  public void Connect();
  // disposes watch dog and calls connect
  public void ReConnect(WatchDog watchDog);
}
```

PS: Volatile.* could be replaced with volatile keyword for the flag variable